# Batch file to Sort folders

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to build simple Batch windows file that does move folder to location based on her name.
For example, if a folder contain new.work.directory-abc, based on the word "work" i want it to  be moved to h:\work.
If the folder name contain old.school.stuff-1s2 based on the word "school" it should be moved to h:\school.

The scanned directory will have new folders all time, so i'll cron the batch to run every 1 hour.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried this options, none of them work for me. I'm still trying because I guess its something I missed.

Comment: What options specifically? There is no built-in option that does everything you ask. You're going to have to put something together. That's why it's called "programming" and not "shopping".

Comment: ofcourse, that's why i'm still trying using mix of this options.

Comment: @Chura - I just tested mine and it absolutely works for what seem to be your specifications.  Try it out and see.  if it doesn't work, comment on my answer about any relevant circumstances / errors and I'll see if I can help you make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot predict at what position the keyword will appear in the name....

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: path to hourly folders:
pushd "c:\temp\hourly"

for /d %%I in (h:\*) do (
    for /d %%x in (*) do (
        for /f %%A in ('echo %%~nx ^| find /i "%%~nI"') do (
            set /p a="Moving %%x to %%I... "<NUL
            move "%%x" "%%I" >NUL
            echo Done.
        )
    )
)
popd
```

**Assumtions:**

- You already have folders on `H:\` into which to move the hourly folders

**How it works**

- Take the name of the first directory on `H:\`
- For each hourly directory, see whether the name of first `H:\` directory is contained within the name of the hourly directory
- If it is, move that hourly directory to the first directory on `H:\`
- Loop to the second directory on `H:\` and repeat.

**Example output**

```
C:\Temp\Hourly>dir *.
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is CE09-0D42

 Directory of C:\Temp\Hourly

02/06/2013  08:57 AM    <DIR>          .
02/06/2013  08:57 AM    <DIR>          ..
10/20/2011  01:17 PM    <DIR>          99 Windows 7 Shortcuts
01/24/2013  02:00 PM    <DIR>          A sysinternals folder
06/18/2012  02:45 PM    <DIR>          funny
01/14/2013  12:47 PM    <DIR>          PortableApps
01/16/2013  09:44 AM    <DIR>          songs
02/06/2013  08:33 AM    <DIR>          This is a temp directory
01/24/2013  02:01 PM    <DIR>          user prompts
06/20/2012  08:00 AM    <DIR>          We Are Anonymous
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
              10 Dir(s)  176,419,254,272 bytes free

C:\Temp\Hourly>dir h:\*.
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is CE09-0D42

 Directory of h:\

08/02/2011  02:24 PM    <DIR>          52bb3510d8007c2f356572
08/16/2011  06:35 AM    <DIR>          ATI
11/07/2012  01:22 AM    <DIR>          Desktop Document
09/20/2011  01:50 PM    <DIR>          Documentum
02/23/2011  08:07 AM    <DIR>          Drivers
01/04/2013  01:17 PM    <DIR>          ffe
12/19/2012  11:19 AM    <DIR>          flex_renamer
01/11/2012  02:44 PM    <DIR>          Games
01/08/2013  12:14 PM    <DIR>          gnuwin32
03/03/2011  09:32 AM    <DIR>          Intel
07/13/2009  10:20 PM    <DIR>          PerfLogs
09/17/2010  01:08 PM    <DIR>          PortableFrozenBubble
08/28/2012  02:27 PM    <DIR>          portaputty
11/13/2012  10:40 AM    <DIR>          Program Files
01/22/2013  02:30 PM    <DIR>          Program Files (x86)
06/01/2012  01:08 PM    <DIR>          SpamBayes
02/24/2011  04:21 PM    <DIR>          Symantec
01/24/2013  01:56 PM    <DIR>          Sysinternals
04/19/2011  08:35 AM    <DIR>          Tcl
04/19/2011  08:30 AM    <DIR>          TclDevKit
02/06/2013  08:52 AM    <DIR>          temp
02/19/2010  05:42 PM    <DIR>          universal print driver
11/07/2012  01:11 AM    <DIR>          Users
02/06/2013  08:56 AM    <DIR>          Windows
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
              24 Dir(s)  176,419,254,272 bytes free

C:\Temp\Hourly>movedir.bat
Moving A sysinternals folder to h:\Sysinternals... Done.
Moving This is a temp directory to h:\temp... Done.
Moving 99 Windows 7 Shortcuts to h:\Windows... Done.

C:\Temp\Hourly>dir *.
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is CE09-0D42

 Directory of c:\Temp\Hourly

02/06/2013  09:00 AM    <DIR>          .
02/06/2013  09:00 AM    <DIR>          ..
06/18/2012  02:45 PM    <DIR>          funny
01/14/2013  12:47 PM    <DIR>          PortableApps
01/16/2013  09:44 AM    <DIR>          songs
01/24/2013  02:01 PM    <DIR>          user prompts
06/20/2012  08:00 AM    <DIR>          We Are Anonymous
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               8 Dir(s)  176,419,254,272 bytes free

C:\Temp\Hourly>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version that I made before seeing rojo's answer (that uses variable 'find and replace')...:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir %~dp0 /b /ad') do call :match %%i
goto continue
    :match
    set dirname=%1
    if "%dirname%"=="work" goto :eof
    if "%dirname%"=="school" goto :eof
    if "%dirname:work=m%" neq "%dirname%" move "%~dp0%dirname%" "%~dp0%work\"
    if "%dirname:school=m%" neq "%dirname%" move "%~dp0%dirname%" "%~dp0%school\"
    goto :eof
:continue
```

For each different category you need, you have to make another

```
if "%dirname%"=="category" goto eof
```

and another

```
if "%dirname:category=m%" neq "%dirname%" move "%~dp0%dirname%" "%~dp0%category\"
```

The 'm' in `"%dirname:category=m%"` is just arbitrary, you can change it to anything else.